# "Error: One of the destinations is zero" on Monero CLI wallet when trying to send a transaction with >6000 ring signatures?

Tags: blockchain, ringct

I wanna do 7500 ring CTs on my transaction but I keep getting that error. Anyone know a work-around?

Also when I lower it to 5000 ring CTs I get "Error: failed to find a suitable way to split transactions".

Is there any way I can make this work? Someone did a 4500 ring CT transaction last year according to a blockchain explorer

Comment: This seems to be due to a bug in the transaction construction algorithm which I think should be posted to the GitHub issue tracker (https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues) with more detailed logs, rather than here.